# microsoft .NET framework required for Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 setup error

Tags: visual-studio-2013

[image]

This message appears when I attempt to install vs2013. I already have installed .NET framework 4.5. I do not understand

Comment: **WHICH** .NET framework version did you install ? Visual Studio 2013 needs **.NET 4.5**

Answer (score 0):

Check the version of Framework installed and the version this installation needs. Often it the simple case of not  having required version installed